# Chrome default focus outline

Tags: google-chrome, focus, outline

I'm trying to remove default focus froom chrome and it works with outline:none; in the same time I want to add an box-shadow but it not working for select .

```
*:focus { outline:none; }

input[type="text"]:focus,input[type="checkbox"]:focus,input[type="password"]:focus,
select:focus, textarea:focus,option:focus{
box-shadow:0 0 2px 0 #0066FF;
-webkit-box-shadow:0 0 9px 0 #86AECC;
z-index:1;
}
```

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/DCjYA/309/

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try this:

```
* { 
    outline-color: lime;
}
```

Comment: The only answer that doesn't break navigation experience for keyboard or assistive technology users… http://www.outlinenone.com/

Answer (score 2):

for me this worked

```
 :focus {
       outline: -webkit-focus-ring-color auto 0;
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

This should also do the trick:

```
a:focus, a:active {
    outline-color: transparent !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Most effective solution on Links only:

```
a:focus, a:active{
    outline:none;
}
```

Or you can disable global:

```
*{
    outline:none;
}
```