# How can I remove a link focus outline on a Chrome extension?

Tags: html, css, google-chrome-extension

I made a simple Chrome extension with links to some frequent bookmarks. When you open it, it automatically focuses on the first link, which is the logo image at the top.

[image]
I think it looks much better without the focus, and the person that I'm making the extension for has no need for accessibility features.

I referenced [this StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9178718/chrome-default-focus-outline) and tried to overwrite this in the CSS with `outline: none;` and `'outline: none !important;`. I've also tried changing the color to a different shade or to transparent using `outline-color: transparent;`. Neither of these has worked.

It's worth mentioning that the outline does not show up when I view the html document in Chrome. It only happens when it's uploaded as a Chrome extension.

You can see my code here: https://github.com/christinahouck/Daniels_Chrome_Extension

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just use this:

```
a:active, a:focus {
   outline: 0;
   border: none;
   -moz-outline-style: none;
}
```