# Strange outline appears in Chrome 83/IE on my Windows 10

Tags: google-chrome, outline

something very, very strange has happened. 
Since a few hours, my Chrome (also IE) shows a different default outline on input. 
Inspecting the code I saw that the outline set is as follows:

outline: -webkit-focus-ring-color auto 1px

and result is like this:
[image]

happens both incognito and in navigation with or without extensions.

how can I restore it ?

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: @Diggy. how can I restore the default outline?

Comment: That is now the new default outline

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it's a new "feature" of chrome 83....(that afflict all S.O.) I hope will be removed soon. 
https://support.google.com/chrome/thread/48974735?hl=en

Answer (score 1):

I think you can achieve it with something like this

```
*:focus {
   outline: 1px solid aliceblue
}
```

so you can define for all of your elements which outline to render on focus.

a similar question can be found here 
[Chrome default focus outline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9178718/chrome-default-focus-outline)

ps: although I think the new chrome outline is ugly as hell, don't forget that disabling it at all is a bad practice
http://www.outlinenone.com/

cheers

Comment: Note: the color matters, as the color needs to have a contrast ratio of 3:1 to the background for accessibility

Answer (score 0):

> The teams at Microsoft Edge and Google Chrome spent the last year
>   collaborating to retheme and improve the functionality of the built-in
>   form controls on Chromium browsers. ... The new focus indicator uses a
>   thick dark ring with a thin white outline, which should improve
>   visibility on both light and dark backgrounds. This is an easy
>   accessibility win that automatically improves the keyboarding
>   experience on a number of sites without developers needing to write
>   any new code. [What's New in Chrome 83](https://blog.chromium.org/2020/03/updates-to-form-controls-and-focus.html)

You could easily totally remove or customize the focus outline for all or any element that you want like below:

```
*:focus {
   outline: none; /* or customize it */
}
```

Comment: For anyone looking for the color value of the NEW focus ring styling in Chrome 83, it's: rgb(0, 33, 245) or #0021F5 (-webkit-focus-ring-color)

Answer (score 0):

```
*:focus {
   outline: none !important; /* or customize it */
}
```

You have to add "!important".